# why ggv causes the vertical split in vim

Tags: vim, vi

I am using vimrc configuration from https://github.com/amix/vimrc. When I press `ggv`, I am getting a vertical split similar to `vsp` in command mode though the split is not exactly 50% like in `vsp`. Can someone help me understand what causes the split behavior when using the key sequence `ggv` in `esc` mode.

I copied the contents in this [gist](https://gist.github.com/surikoya/30d37f46c60f90dee6a91eae202057b1).

Comment: Can you tell us what is displayed when you execute `:verbose map ggv`?

Comment: I get the message "No mapping found"

Comment: The ultimate cause is your refusal to configure Vim yourself.

Comment: cannot agree with romainl more.. another suggestion is, do a binary search on your vimrc, to locate the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Provided the link you gave, the `vimrc` is a result of a combination of a lot of pieces, if you don't pick the basic option.

Searching through the repo I find 2 possible sources for the `ggv`, but possibly just `gv` command.

```
sources_non_forked/ack.vim/autoload/ack.vim:120:    " We just map the 'go' and 'gv' mappings to close on autoclose, wtf?
sources_non_forked/ack.vim/doc/ack.txt:136:      \ "gv": "<C-W><CR><C-W>H<C-W>b<C-W>J" }
sources_non_forked/ack.vim/doc/ack.txt:259:gv                  open in vertical split, keeping focus on the results.
sources_non_forked/ack.vim/doc/ack.txt:298:              \ 'gv': '<C-W><CR><C-W>L<C-W>p<C-W>J' }
sources_non_forked/ack.vim/doc/ack_quick_help.txt:12: *gv:*  to open in vertical split, keeping focus on the results
sources_non_forked/ack.vim/plugin/ack.vim:38:      \ "gv": "<C-W><CR><C-W>H<C-W>b<C-W>J" }
sources_non_forked/ack.vim/README.md:87:    gv   to open in vertical split, keeping focus on the results
sources_non_forked/ag.vim/autoload/ag.vim:173:      exe 'nnoremap <silent> <buffer> gv :let b:height=winheight(0)<CR><C-w><CR><C-w>H:' . l:matches_window_prefix . 'open<CR><C-w>J:exe printf(":normal %d\<lt>c-w>_", b:height)<CR>'
sources_non_forked/ag.vim/autoload/ag.vim:183:        echom "ag.vim keys: q=quit <cr>/e/t/h/v=enter/edit/tab/split/vsplit go/T/H/gv=preview versions of same"
sources_non_forked/ag.vim/doc/ag.txt:170:gv                  open in vertical split silently.
sources_non_forked/ag.vim/README.md:69:    gv   to open in vertical split silently
```

So in the case of `ack.vim` it maps it to a split with results.
In the case of `ag.vim` it maps for a similar purpose. Per the README `ag.vim` is deprecated in favor of `ack.vim`.

## Original Answer w/o Source Link

I run a fairly basic VIM setup. The link you provided was broken, but based on what you said, it sounds like the file contains a new mapping of that key sequence to a series of commands. The mapping would look like the following.

```
map ggv :split<CR>:res+10<CR>
```

In this case, any time I type `ggv` in visual mode, it would split the window and resize the current window down 10 lines.

If you don't want this functionality, you'll have to remove it from your `vimrc` and then restart all your vim sessions or you could use `:source /path/to/vimrc` in each active session.

Comment: After additional watching I found `gg` took me to the beginning of file and `v` introduced the window split. So it is just `v` that split the window vertically.